# Getting all images with mediastore on Android API ≤28 and API ≥29

Tags: android, sdk, mediastore

How can I use mediastore to get all images that will work for Android API≤28 and API≥29.

Comment: Note that media inside hidden folders (or with a .nomedia file inside them) won't be visible to MediaStore. I haven't found a workaround for that.

Comment: Ok. How does one do it for the ones not in hidden folders?

Comment: The answers below should work, did you test them?

Answer (score 0):

In the example below all music is obtained from Mediastore
Instead of
MediaStore.**Audio**.Media.
use
MediaStore.**Images**.Media.

```
private final String track_id = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID;
private final String bucket_displayname = MediaStore.Audio.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME;
private final String track_no = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK;
private final String track_name = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;
private final String artist = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST;
private final String artist_id = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID;
private final String duration = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION;
private final String album = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM;
private final String composer = MediaStore.Audio.Media.COMPOSER;
private final String year = MediaStore.Audio.Media.YEAR;
private  String path = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
private final String date_added = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED;
private final String genre = MediaStore.Audio.Media.GENRE;
private final String genre_id = MediaStore.Audio.Media.GENRE_ID;

   public Cursor getAllTracks(Context context) {
    // gets all tracks
    if (context != null) {
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        String[] columns =null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.Q ) {
            columns = new String[]{track_id, track_no, artist, track_name,
                    album, duration, path, year, composer, genre, genre_id};
        }else{
            columns = new String[]{track_id, track_no, artist, track_name,
                    album, duration, path, year, composer};
        }
        Uri uri = uris.get_audio_media_uri();
        Cursor crs=cr.query(uri, columns, null, null, null);
      
        return crs;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and where uri is

```
public Uri get_audio_media_uri(){
    Uri uri_to_use = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        uri_to_use = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
    } else {
        uri_to_use = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }
    return uri_to_use;
}
```

Comment: Okay
What part should be run in a worker thread so it doesn't affect UI. How exactly should I do it?

Comment: it takes no time at all, all it does is return stuff from the media database

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Code to get all the images from storage.

```
private fun queryImageStorage() {
    
            val imageProjection = arrayOf(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID
            )
    
            val imageSortOrder = "${MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN} DESC"
    
            val cursor = contentResolver.query(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    imageProjection,
                    null,
                    null,
                    imageSortOrder
            )
    
            cursor.use {
                it?.let {
                    val idColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
                    val nameColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
                    val sizeColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE)
                    val dateColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN)
    
                    while (it.moveToNext()) {
                        val id = it.getLong(idColumn)
                        val name = it.getString(nameColumn)
                        val size = it.getString(sizeColumn)
                        val date = it.getString(dateColumn)
    
                        val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                id
                        )
                        // add the URI to the list 
                       // generate the thumbnail
                       val thumbnail = (this as Context).contentResolver.loadThumbnail(contentUri, Size(480, 480), null)
    
                    }
                } ?: kotlin.run {
                    Log.e("TAG", "Cursor is null!")
                }
            }
        }
```